# d3 tooltip. Collapsible tree. Error when .on(mouseover,function(....)) is called

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I am trying to add Tooltips to a collapsible tree and i am facing issues with that. The error appears to happen at this block of code as shown below (i shall attach complete code snippet as well for debugging purpose)

```
 // Transition nodes to their new position.
          var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
              .duration(duration)
              .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; });

          nodeUpdate.select("circle")
              .attr('r',function(d) { return d.size;  })
              .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; })
              .attr('cursor', 'pointer')
              .on("mouseover", mouseover)
              .on("mousemove", function(d){mousemove(d);})
              .on("mouseout", mouseout);
```

**Error Msg**: Uncaught TypeError: nodeUpdate.select(...).attr(...).style(...).attr(...).on is not a function
The .on function is not recognised as a function. I believe this has got to do with transitions of nodes but i am not really sure on how to go about fixing this.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
  div.container {
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  header {
    height: 35px;
    padding: 1em;
    color: white;
    background-color: gray;
    clear: left;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-family: Calibri;
    font-size: 35px;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  
  .node {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  
  .node circle {
    fill: #fff;
    stroke: steelblue;
    stroke-width: 1.5px;
  }
  
  .node text {
    font: 13px sans-serif;
  }
  
  .link {
    fill: none;
    stroke-opacity: 0.4;
    stroke: purple;
    stroke-width: 3.5px;
  }
  
  #content img {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
  }
  
  h2 {
    font-family: Calibri;
    font-size: 35px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  div.container1 span {
    top: 50%;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    div.tooltip {
      position: absolute;
      text-align: center;
      width: 60px;
      height: 28px;
      padding: 2px;
      font: 12px sans-serif;
      background: lightsteelblue;
      border: 0px;
      border-radius: 8px;
      pointer-events: none;
    }
  }
</style>

<body bgcolor='#F8F9F9'>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
  <div class="container">

    <table>
      <tr>
        <td width="90%">
          <div id="hier" align="left">
            <tr>
              <script>
                var margin = {
                    top: 20,
                    right: 120,
                    bottom: 20,
                    left: 120
                  },
                  width = 1500 - margin.right - margin.left,
                  height = 800 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
                var flare = {
                  "name": "AON",
                  "size": 4,
                  "children": [{
                      "name": "India",
                      "size": 4,
                      "children": [{
                        "name": "ARS",
                        "size": 4,
                        "children": [
                          {
                            "name": "hhh",
                            "size": 4
                          },
                          {
                            "name": "AAA",
                            "size": 4
                          },
                          {
                            "name": "BBB",
                            "size": 4
                          },
                          {
                            "name": "cCC",
                            "size": 8
                          },
                          {
                            "name": "ddd",
                            "size": 4
                          },
                          {
                            "name": "eee",
                            "size": 4
                          },
                          {
                            "name": "fff",
                            "size": 4
                          },
                          {
                            "name": "ggg",
                            "size": 4
                          },
                          {
                            "name": "hhh",
                            "size": 4
                          },
                          {
                            "name": "www",
                            "size": 4
                          },
                          {
                            "name": "qwww",
                            "size": 8
                          },
                          {
                            "name": "sd",
                            "size": 4
                          },
                          {
                            "name": "tere",
                            "size": 4
                          },
                          {
                            "name": "rtr",
                            "size": 4
                          },
                          {
                            "name": "wqw",
                            "size": 4
                          },
                          {
                            "name": "hrfg",
                            "size": 4
                          }
                        ]
                      }]
                    },
                    {
                      "name": "Singapore",
                      "size": 4,
                      "children": [{
                          "name": "H&B",
                          "size": 4,
                          "children": [{
                              "name": "aasd",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "sdw",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "ghrr",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "tyr",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "wew",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "ere",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "wew",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "eds",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "hrtr",
                              "size": 8
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "wew",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "uyt",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "wew",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "wewe",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "yrt",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "uyu",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "erewr",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "wew",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "kyjy",
                              "size": 4
                            }
                          ]
                        },
                        {
                          "name": "GCP",
                          "size": 4,
                          "children": [{
                              "name": "wew",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "sdsf",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "wewt",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "wetdse",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "wetw",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "qwsd",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "yrytw",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "wewax",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "jttut",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "scscw",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "wetvd",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "wewe",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "zc",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "wew",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "zerete",
                              "size": 8
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "sdaxa",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "yeer",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "sdaxa",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "wewretre",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "ssdsrere",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "asdsdere",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "asdsdere",
                              "size": 4
                            }
                          ]
                        }
                      ]
                    },
                    {
                      "name": "US",
                      "size": 4,
                      "children": [{
                          "name": "Benfield",
                          "size": 4,
                          "children": [{
                              "name": "wes",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "sd",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "dds",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "sdsd",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "ere",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "ryr",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "ty",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "wewe",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "ggrt",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "wetyr",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "wew",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "hrfg",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "wew",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "hhf",
                              "size": 8
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "ere",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "vfgd",
                              "size": 4
                            }
                          ]
                        },
                        {
                          "name": "GCP",
                          "size": 4,
                          "children": [{
                              "name": "xx",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "wqwq",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "xasa",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "ooo",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "ppp",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "ll",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "lljk",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "kjjk",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "kui",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "yu",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "li",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "uyu",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "yuik",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "yjm",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "yu",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "yikm",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "yu",
                              "size": 8
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "mmui",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "yum",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "kyuyy",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "dffgy",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "erfdr",
                              "size": 4
                            }
                          ]
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                };

                var i = 0,
                  duration = 750,
                  root;

                var tree = d3.layout.tree()
                  .size([height, width]);

                var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
                  .projection(function(d) {
                    return [d.y, d.x];
                  });

                var svg = d3.select("#hier").append("svg")
                  .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
                  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                  .append("g")
                  .attr("transform", "translate(" + 500 + "," + margin.top + ")");

                var div = d3.select("#hier").append("div")
                  .attr("class", "tooltip")
                  .style("opacity", 0);

                root = flare;
                root.x0 = height / 2;
                root.y0 = 0;

                function collapse(d) {
                  if (d.children) {
                    d._children = d.children;
                    d._children.forEach(collapse);
                    d.children = null;
                  }
                }

                root.children.forEach(collapse);
                update(root);


                d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", "800px");

                function update(source) {

                  // Compute the new tree layout.
                  var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
                    links = tree.links(nodes);

                  // Normalize for fixed-depth.
                  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
                    d.y = d.depth * 180;
                  });

                  // Update the nodes…
                  var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
                    .data(nodes, function(d) {
                      return d.id || (d.id = ++i);
                    });

                  // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
                  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
                    .attr("class", "node")
                    .attr("transform", function(d) {
                      return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")";
                    })
                    .on("click", click);

                  nodeEnter.append("circle")
                    .attr("r", 1e-6)
                    .style("fill", function(d) {
                      return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
                    });

                  nodeEnter.append("text")
                    .attr("x", function(d) {
                      return d.children || d._children ? -10 : 10;
                    })
                    .attr("dy", ".35em")
                    .attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
                      return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start";
                    })
                    .text(function(d) {
                      return d.name;
                    })
                    .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

                  // Transition nodes to their new position.
                  var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
                    .duration(duration)
                    .attr("transform", function(d) {
                      return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
                    });

                  nodeUpdate.select("circle")
                    .attr('r', function(d) {
                      return d.size;
                    })
                    .style("fill", function(d) {
                      return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
                    })
                    .attr('cursor', 'pointer')
                    .on("mouseover", mouseover)
                    .on("mousemove", function(d) {
                      mousemove(d);
                    })
                    .on("mouseout", mouseout);

                  function mouseover() {
                    div.transition()
                      .duration(300)
                      .style("opacity", 1);
                  }

                  function mousemove(d) {
                    div
                      .text(d.name)
                      .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
                      .style("top", (d3.event.pageY) + "px");
                  }

                  function mouseout() {
                    div.transition()
                      .duration(300)
                      .style("opacity", 1e-6);
                  }


                  nodeUpdate.select("text")
                    .style("fill-opacity", 1);

                  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
                  var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
                    .duration(duration)
                    .attr("transform", function(d) {
                      return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")";
                    })
                    .remove();

                  nodeExit.select("circle")
                    .attr("r", 1e-6);

                  nodeExit.select("text")
                    .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

                  // Update the links…
                  var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
                    .data(links, function(d) {
                      return d.target.id;
                    });

                  // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
                  link.enter().insert("path", "g")
                    .attr("class", "link")
                    .attr("d", function(d) {
                      var o = {
                        x: source.x0,
                        y: source.y0
                      };
                      return diagonal({
                        source: o,
                        target: o
                      });
                    });

                  // Transition links to their new position.
                  link.transition()
                    .duration(duration)
                    .attr("d", diagonal);

                  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
                  link.exit().transition()
                    .duration(duration)
                    .attr("d", function(d) {
                      var o = {
                        x: source.x,
                        y: source.y
                      };
                      return diagonal({
                        source: o,
                        target: o
                      });
                    })
                    .remove();

                  // Stash the old positions for transition.
                  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
                    d.x0 = d.x;
                    d.y0 = d.y;
                  });
                }

                // Toggle children on click.
                function click(d) {
                  if (d.children) {
                    d._children = d.children;
                    d.children = null;
                  } else {
                    d.children = d._children;
                    d._children = null;
                  }
                  update(d);
                }
              </script>
            </tr>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td width="10%">

        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
```

The error is reproducible when ran on the code snippet. Kindly help me understand the fix for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A transition is not a typical selection. From the [d3v3 documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Transitions.mdhttp://):

> A transition is a special type of selection where the operators apply
>   smoothly over time rather than instantaneously. You derive a
>   transition from a selection using the transition operator. While
>   transitions generally support the same operators as selections (such
>   as attr and style), not all operators are supported; for example, you
>   must append elements before a transition starts. A remove operator is
>   provided for convenient removal of elements when the transition ends.

You are attempting to place `.on` events on a transition:

```
              // Transition nodes to their new position.
              var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
                .duration(duration)
                .attr( .... });

              nodeUpdate.select("circle")
                .attr(......)
                .on("mouseover", mouseover)
                .on("mousemove", function(d) {
                  mousemove(d);
                })
                .on("mouseout", mouseout);
```

*transition.select() selects the first descendant element that matches the specified selector string, if any, and returns a transition on the resulting selection ([API documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Transitions.md#select))*

However, there is no `.on` method for a d3 transition in v3. There is however, a `.each` method (renamed `.on` in v4). However, the range of events (type) allowed for the method are three:

> If type is specified, adds a listener for transition events,
>   supporting "start", "end" and "interrupt" events. The listener will be
>   invoked for each individual element in the transition. ([documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Transitions.md#each))

Instead of using the transition selection to apply .on events, try using a typical selection. This will allow you to use .on as you want. I changed this line

```
nodeUpdate.select("circle")
```

To

```
d3.selectAll("circle")
```

And this applies the .on events without issue to the nodes. The tree diagram appears to work as intended in the modified snippet below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
  div.container {
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  header {
    height: 35px;
    padding: 1em;
    color: white;
    background-color: gray;
    clear: left;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-family: Calibri;
    font-size: 35px;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  
  .node {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  
  .node circle {
    fill: #fff;
    stroke: steelblue;
    stroke-width: 1.5px;
  }
  
  .node text {
    font: 13px sans-serif;
  }
  
  .link {
    fill: none;
    stroke-opacity: 0.4;
    stroke: purple;
    stroke-width: 3.5px;
  }
  
  #content img {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
  }
  
  h2 {
    font-family: Calibri;
    font-size: 35px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  div.container1 span {
    top: 50%;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    div.tooltip {
      position: absolute;
      text-align: center;
      width: 60px;
      height: 28px;
      padding: 2px;
      font: 12px sans-serif;
      background: lightsteelblue;
      border: 0px;
      border-radius: 8px;
      pointer-events: none;
    }
  }
</style>

<body bgcolor='#F8F9F9'>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
  <div class="container">

    <table>
      <tr>
        <td width="90%">
          <div id="hier" align="left">
            <tr>
              <script>
                var margin = {
                    top: 20,
                    right: 120,
                    bottom: 20,
                    left: 120
                  },
                  width = 1500 - margin.right - margin.left,
                  height = 800 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
                var flare = {
                  "name": "AON",
                  "size": 4,
                  "children": [{
                      "name": "India",
                      "size": 4,
                      "children": [{
                        "name": "ARS",
                        "size": 4,
                        "children": [
                          {
                            "name": "hhh",
                            "size": 4
                          },
                          {
                            "name": "AAA",
                            "size": 4
                          },
                          {
                            "name": "BBB",
                            "size": 4
                          },
                          {
                            "name": "cCC",
                            "size": 8
                          },
                          {
                            "name": "ddd",
                            "size": 4
                          },
                          {
                            "name": "eee",
                            "size": 4
                          },
                          {
                            "name": "fff",
                            "size": 4
                          },
                          {
                            "name": "ggg",
                            "size": 4
                          },
                          {
                            "name": "hhh",
                            "size": 4
                          },
                          {
                            "name": "www",
                            "size": 4
                          },
                          {
                            "name": "qwww",
                            "size": 8
                          },
                          {
                            "name": "sd",
                            "size": 4
                          },
                          {
                            "name": "tere",
                            "size": 4
                          },
                          {
                            "name": "rtr",
                            "size": 4
                          },
                          {
                            "name": "wqw",
                            "size": 4
                          },
                          {
                            "name": "hrfg",
                            "size": 4
                          }
                        ]
                      }]
                    },
                    {
                      "name": "Singapore",
                      "size": 4,
                      "children": [{
                          "name": "H&B",
                          "size": 4,
                          "children": [{
                              "name": "aasd",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "sdw",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "ghrr",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "tyr",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "wew",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "ere",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "wew",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "eds",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "hrtr",
                              "size": 8
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "wew",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "uyt",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "wew",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "wewe",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "yrt",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "uyu",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "erewr",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "wew",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "kyjy",
                              "size": 4
                            }
                          ]
                        },
                        {
                          "name": "GCP",
                          "size": 4,
                          "children": [{
                              "name": "wew",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "sdsf",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "wewt",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "wetdse",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "wetw",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "qwsd",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "yrytw",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "wewax",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "jttut",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "scscw",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "wetvd",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "wewe",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "zc",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "wew",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "zerete",
                              "size": 8
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "sdaxa",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "yeer",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "sdaxa",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "wewretre",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "ssdsrere",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "asdsdere",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "asdsdere",
                              "size": 4
                            }
                          ]
                        }
                      ]
                    },
                    {
                      "name": "US",
                      "size": 4,
                      "children": [{
                          "name": "Benfield",
                          "size": 4,
                          "children": [{
                              "name": "wes",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "sd",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "dds",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "sdsd",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "ere",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "ryr",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "ty",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "wewe",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "ggrt",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "wetyr",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "wew",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "hrfg",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "wew",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "hhf",
                              "size": 8
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "ere",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "vfgd",
                              "size": 4
                            }
                          ]
                        },
                        {
                          "name": "GCP",
                          "size": 4,
                          "children": [{
                              "name": "xx",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "wqwq",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "xasa",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "ooo",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "ppp",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "ll",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "lljk",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "kjjk",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "kui",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "yu",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "li",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "uyu",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "yuik",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "yjm",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "yu",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "yikm",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "yu",
                              "size": 8
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "mmui",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "yum",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "kyuyy",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "dffgy",
                              "size": 4
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "erfdr",
                              "size": 4
                            }
                          ]
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                };

                var i = 0,
                  duration = 750,
                  root;

                var tree = d3.layout.tree()
                  .size([height, width]);

                var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
                  .projection(function(d) {
                    return [d.y, d.x];
                  });

                var svg = d3.select("#hier").append("svg")
                  .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
                  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                  .append("g")
                  .attr("transform", "translate(" + 500 + "," + margin.top + ")");

                var div = d3.select("#hier").append("div")
                  .attr("class", "tooltip")
                  .style("opacity", 0);

                root = flare;
                root.x0 = height / 2;
                root.y0 = 0;

                function collapse(d) {
                  if (d.children) {
                    d._children = d.children;
                    d._children.forEach(collapse);
                    d.children = null;
                  }
                }

                root.children.forEach(collapse);
                update(root);


                d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", "800px");

                function update(source) {

                  // Compute the new tree layout.
                  var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
                    links = tree.links(nodes);

                  // Normalize for fixed-depth.
                  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
                    d.y = d.depth * 180;
                  });

                  // Update the nodes…
                  var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
                    .data(nodes, function(d) {
                      return d.id || (d.id = ++i);
                    });

                  // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
                  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
                    .attr("class", "node")
                    .attr("transform", function(d) {
                      return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")";
                    })
                    .on("click", click);

                  nodeEnter.append("circle")
                    .attr("r", 1e-6)
                    .style("fill", function(d) {
                      return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
                    });

                  nodeEnter.append("text")
                    .attr("x", function(d) {
                      return d.children || d._children ? -10 : 10;
                    })
                    .attr("dy", ".35em")
                    .attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
                      return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start";
                    })
                    .text(function(d) {
                      return d.name;
                    })
                    .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

                  // Transition nodes to their new position.
                  var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
                    .duration(duration)
                    .attr("transform", function(d) {
                      return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
                    });

                  d3.selectAll("circle")
                    .attr('r', function(d) {
                      return d.size;
                    })
                    .style("fill", function(d) {
                      return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
                    })
                    .attr('cursor', 'pointer')
                    .on("mouseover", mouseover)
                    .on("mousemove", function(d) {
                      mousemove(d);
                    })
                    .on("mouseout", mouseout);

                  function mouseover() {
                    div.transition()
                      .duration(300)
                      .style("opacity", 1);
                  }

                  function mousemove(d) {
                    div
                      .text(d.name)
                      .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
                      .style("top", (d3.event.pageY) + "px");
                  }

                  function mouseout() {
                    div.transition()
                      .duration(300)
                      .style("opacity", 1e-6);
                  }


                  nodeUpdate.select("text")
                    .style("fill-opacity", 1);

                  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
                  var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
                    .duration(duration)
                    .attr("transform", function(d) {
                      return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")";
                    })
                    .remove();

                  nodeExit.select("circle")
                    .attr("r", 1e-6);

                  nodeExit.select("text")
                    .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

                  // Update the links…
                  var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
                    .data(links, function(d) {
                      return d.target.id;
                    });

                  // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
                  link.enter().insert("path", "g")
                    .attr("class", "link")
                    .attr("d", function(d) {
                      var o = {
                        x: source.x0,
                        y: source.y0
                      };
                      return diagonal({
                        source: o,
                        target: o
                      });
                    });

                  // Transition links to their new position.
                  link.transition()
                    .duration(duration)
                    .attr("d", diagonal);

                  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
                  link.exit().transition()
                    .duration(duration)
                    .attr("d", function(d) {
                      var o = {
                        x: source.x,
                        y: source.y
                      };
                      return diagonal({
                        source: o,
                        target: o
                      });
                    })
                    .remove();

                  // Stash the old positions for transition.
                  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
                    d.x0 = d.x;
                    d.y0 = d.y;
                  });
                }

                // Toggle children on click.
                function click(d) {
                  if (d.children) {
                    d._children = d.children;
                    d.children = null;
                  } else {
                    d.children = d._children;
                    d._children = null;
                  }
                  update(d);
                }
              </script>
            </tr>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td width="10%">

        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew. Perfect explaination. Good to learn new stuff like this.